# Python draw contours of multiple specific elements

Tags: python, contour, opencv

I have a binary image and I'm trying to contour elements that are prolonged (not circles).
If I try to contour one element - it contours with the correct colour. But how to do it when I have a for loop? It only shows the last element with the correct colour.
[contour of last element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oCZH.png)
Here is my code:
import math

```
for i in range(len(contours)):
    ctr = contours[i] 
    M = cv2.moments(ctr)
    cX = M['m10']/M['m00']
    cY = M['m01']/M['m00']
    
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    cv2.drawContours(rgb, contours, i, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    rot_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(ctr)
    box = np.int64(cv2.boxPoints(rot_rect))

    xx1=(box[0,0]+box[1,0])/2
    yy1=(box[0,1]+box[1,1])/2
    xx2=(box[2,0]+box[1,0])/2
    yy2=(box[2,1]+box[1,1])/2

    distance1 = math.sqrt( ((xx1-cX)**2)+((yy1-cY)**2) )
    distance2 = math.sqrt( ((xx2-cX)**2)+((yy2-cY)**2) )
    
    if (distance1 < 0.5*distance2) or (0.5*distance1 > distance2):
        cv2.drawContours(rgb, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        plt.imshow(rgb)
    else:
        cv2.drawContours(rgb, [box], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        plt.imshow(rgb)
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me. I saved relevant contours to relevant arrays (note that they must be arrays and not lists, so we can use them in the contour drawing method).
[the result of contouring specific elements in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqLRT.png)

```
import math
ctr1= []
ctr2= []
for i in range(len(contours)):
    ctr = contours[i] 
    M = cv2.moments(ctr)
    cX = M['m10']/M['m00']
    cY = M['m01']/M['m00']
    
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    rot_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(ctr)
    box = np.int64(cv2.boxPoints(rot_rect))

    xx1=(box[0,0]+box[1,0])/2
    yy1=(box[0,1]+box[1,1])/2
    xx2=(box[2,0]+box[1,0])/2
    yy2=(box[2,1]+box[1,1])/2

    distance1 = math.sqrt( ((xx1-cX)**2)+((yy1-cY)**2) )
    distance2 = math.sqrt( ((xx2-cX)**2)+((yy2-cY)**2) )
    
    if (distance1 < 0.5*distance2) or (0.5*distance1 > distance2):
        ctr1.append(np.asarray(ctr, dtype=np.int32))
    else:
        ctr2.append(np.asarray(ctr, dtype=np.int32))

cv2.drawContours(rgb, ctr1, -1, (255, 0, 0),5)
cv2.drawContours(rgb, ctr2, -1, (0, 255, 0),2)
```